# MSP doesn't install all updated files

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, msp, msi-patch

If i have two MSI packages:

package A) 2.0.1234  (initial_product.msi)
packacge B) 2.0.2300 (updated_product.msi)

I can create a patch in installshield that generates an MSP from the two to upgrade 2.0.1234 to 2.0.2300. What's strange is, the new files from updated_product.msi aren't getting installed. Files that are being updated get updated, though. The new files are under the AlwaysInstal feature.

It essentially results in a non-standard install, since you're missing new files from the new version, but your old files are getting updated with the newer version of the DLL's.

What would cause them to not be installed? the MSP is being ran with the default of REINSTALLMODE=omus REINSTALL=ALL

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in this case was I wasn't using the option to sequence the files based on a previous MSI file. When you build an updated MSI, it's important that you point it at the original so that it doesn't come up with all new file sequence numbers.

(Just noticed I had left this question open for the last couple years and wanted to make sure anyone else running into this issue can find the answer to this question)

Answer (score 0):

Any chance that the MSP names don't match the original names (case sensitive counts! see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368060(v=VS.85).aspx )?

Comment: Nope - it's only new files that are being missed, the ones from the original are being updated.

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact I'm targetting more than one MSI and I'm using automatic sequencing... although, I cant' find any information on how I could go about sequencing them manually, everything I've found is generic and doesn't give any real example.